# How to clear local storage of the browser when restarting or shut downing the PC

Tags: angular, browser, local-storage

I'm currently working on an application which can be opened in multiple tabs. Therefore I need to stire certain items in local storage. I have implemented a method to clear local storage items when closing the last tab or the browser. It works fine closing last tab and browser though isn't work with shutdown or restart the browser. After shutdown or restart I can find those local storage lements as it;s. I'm using angular for the development and is there a way to clear local storage of the browser when restarting or shut downing the PC.

I have implemented a method to clear local storage items when closing the last tab or the browser by using beforeunload method.
Cannot use in session storage as the application needs to support multiple tabs.

It works well with browser and tab closes

Answer (score 1):

just a quick thought how about clearing as soon as you encounter first open? and clear again based on timestamp check? also another way is
To suppress caching of the Set-Cookie header: Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie".

Comment: FYI: `no-cache` does not suppress caching. `no-store` does it.

Comment: @niran How to identify encounter first open by differentiating refresh and open after shut down

Comment: In client-side, nop. The OS level details are not exposed to the to run-time in browsers. So may be its not possible.